# Weird AngularJS checkbox behviour

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns" >
    <label for="campaignPaused">Paused</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="campaign.paused"class="check_box" />
    <p>campaign.paused == {{campaign.paused}}</p>
```

Initially, the debug text shows that `$scope.campaign.paused` is false, which is correct, and the checkbox is correctly unchecked.

If I click the checkbox, the debug text changes to true, but the checkbox remains visually unchecked.

Subsequent clicks to the checkbox have no effect.

Now for the weird part: if I remove that `ng-click="CampaignClicked($event, campaign.campaign_id)"` then the checkbox works correctly!

Aha!, I thought - the click on the checkbox is peculating up to its parent. And, it was, although that `CampaignClicked()` simply swallowed the event and returned, sicne it wasn't ewxpecting ot be clicked.

To make things clearer, I changed the checkbox to

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="campaign.paused" ng-click="SwallowClick($event)" class="check_box" />
```

where I have declared

```
$scope.SwallowClick = function($event)
{
   if ($event.cancelable) 
       $event.preventDefault();

     $event.stopPropagation();   

   return false;   // don't handle event further
}
```

But, the checkbox is still behaving as before.

Can anyone see why? (Note that if I move the checkbox before the DIV, it works correctly)

Comment: can your provide a demo in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: you're explicitely preventing the event from doing its default action and to propagate, and yet you're wondering why it doesn't do its default action (checking the checkbox) and propagate. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I am preventing a click on a checkbox within a DIV from propagating out to the DIV. I would still like the checkbox to toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
if ($event.cancelable) 
       $event.preventDefault();
```

It's preventing further action within checkbox. Remove that code from your event.

From **[`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)**

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be
>   triggered

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/kchrsLga/)**</kbd>

Comment: Why did it not work at first, before I added `ng-click="SwallowClick($event)" ` to the checkbox?

Comment: It won't work for the code that i mentioned in my answer

Comment: Nvm, I reworked all of the event propagation in the app